# Lists in classes losing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, object

I'm trying to parsing text from a file, the first character in a line will be used to decide of what type the remaining text should be.
**'?' - Question, '#' - Description, '!' - Answers, and the next number will determine what is the correct answer.**
I want to have an object that stores the respective data, and a class that holds references to those objects (list of objects). The amount of answers can vary, so I tried to use a list for that.
The problem is that the returned "answers" list is blank.
Where did I go wrong?

```
class Question:                                         
def __init__(self, ques, desc, n_ans, corr, ans):
    self.ques = ques
    self.desc = desc
    self.n_ans = n_ans
    self.corr = corr
    self.ans = ans
    print(self.ans)
def get(self):
    print(self.ans)
    return [self.ques, self.desc, self.n_ans, self.corr, self.ans]

class Question_handler:
arr_ans = []
array = []
firstTime = True
def __init__(self):
    self.num_ans = 0
    self.cor_ans = 0
    self.ques = None
    self.desc = None
def question(self, ques):                # if it isn't the first time reaching a line starts with '?'            
    if self.firstTime == True:           # the data is made into an instance of Question
        pass
    else:
        self.array.append(Question(self.ques, self.desc, self.num_ans, self.cor_ans, self.arr_ans)) # List of objects
        self.ques = None                 # Reset everything
        self.desc = None
        self.num_ans = 0
        self.cor_ans = 0
        self.arr_ans.clear()
    self.ques = ques
    self.firstTime = False
def description(self, desc):
    if self.desc == None:
        self.desc = desc
    else:
        self.desc = self.desc + '\n' + desc
def answer(self, ans):
    self.arr_ans.append(ans)                    # Append answers (line starts with '!') to list
    self.num_ans = len(self.arr_ans)
def correct(self, num):
    if num >= 1 and num <= len(self.arr_ans):
        self.cor_ans = num
    else:
        self.cor_ans = 0
def end(self):                                  # Reach EOF
    if self.ques == None:
        pass
    else:
        self.question(None)                     # To push the remaining data
def get(self, Nques):                           # Get info of Question
    if Nques <= len(self.array) and Nques >= 1:
        return self.array[Nques - 1].get()

QQ = Question_handler()
Qfile = open('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/test/test.txt','r')
Qdata = Qfile.readlines()
for line in Qdata:
    Qline = line[1:-1]
    if line[0] == '?':
        QQ.question(Qline)
        continue
    if line[0] == '#':
        QQ.description(Qline)
        continue
    if line[0] == '!':
        QQ.answer(Qline)
        continue
    if line[0].isnumeric():
        QQ.correct(int(line[0]))
        continue
else:
    QQ.end()                                # EOF
print(QQ.get(1))
print(QQ.get(2))
print(QQ.get(3))
```

TXT file

```
?Cau 1
#Test so 1
!abc
!def
!ghj
!ikl
3
?Cau 2
#Test so 2
!100
!1000
!10000
2
?Question 3
!A
!B
!C
!D
!E
5
```

Output

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghj', 'ikl']
['100', '1000', '10000']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
[]
['Cau 1', 'Test so 1', 4, 3, []]
[]
['Cau 2', 'Test so 2', 3, 2, []]
[]
['Question 3', None, 5, 5, []]
```

Comment: what do you think this `self.arr_ans.clear()` does?

Comment: @njzk2 I think it should clear the list so that I can re-appending 'answers' to it?

Comment: You're clearing the list and then asking why the list is empty. If you don't want an empty list, don't clear it.

Comment: @GiaBaoHuynh right. Of course, that's the same list for all questions, since you pass it here: `Question(self.ques, self.desc, self.num_ans, self.cor_ans, self.arr_ans)`. There are typically 2 approaches to fix this: either create a copy in `Question`: `self.ans = ans[:]`, or create a new list each time, instead of clearing: `self.arr_ans = []`